# How to set a custom python include directory when compiling paraview

Tags: python, paraview

I'm trying to compile Paraview on a Linux machine where various versions of python are installed in custom places. I can specify the library via `$PYTHON_LIBRARY`, but how do I specify the include path? I've tried to export `$PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR="..."` and `$PYTHON_INCLUDE_PATH="..."` but it keeps looking in `/usr/include/python2.7/`.

The error message is

```
./makeParaView4
    No python headers found in /usr/include/python2.7/
    Please install python headers or deactivate 
    python support by not using the -python option
```

How do I fix this?

I'm using ParaView-4.1.0 and the install script coming with OpenFOAM 2.3.0.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Old, but encountered and fixed it in OpenFOAM 2.4.x

makeParaview4 invokes the following script:

```
. etc/tools/ParaView4Functions
```

So, edit this file to point to the correct PYTHON include dir:

```
    pythonInclude=/usr/include/python$pythonMajor
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be with the script you're using to build ParaView. Edit the script and look for places where its choosing the python2.7.